# Automatically generated EF code in WebApi doesn't work on Azure but does work locally when testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api

I connected my project to a sql database which is on Azure as well.
When testing locally,

this url works fine.  ->`http://localhost:3287/api/Questions`

but when testing on Azure  --> http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/Questions
it fails and returns an error message in JSON format as you can see below.

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "$id": "2",
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Error getting value from 'company_answer' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.question_70E4093AC2C7FDC38798C82820B9E2C1CBF9627487D0F09FFAC57467331A277B'.",
    "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
      "$id": "3",
      "Message": "An error has occurred.",
      "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.",
      "ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException",
      "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.question_70E4093AC2C7FDC38798C82820B9E2C1CBF9627487D0F09FFAC57467331A277B.get_company_answer()\r\n   at Getcompany_answer(Object )\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)",
      "InnerException": {
        "$id": "4",
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried other urls such as:
**http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/Questions/3**
And it works fine on both local and Azure. (Really strange!)

I did see **The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.**

And added this

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            ((DefaultContractResolver)json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting =
                Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "ActionApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

into my WebApiConfig.cs,  but it doesn't fix the problem.

I also saw :  **There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.**

So I checked this : **MultipleActiveResultSets=True;**
It is in my connection string.

But my problem is still there.

Here is the generated code by VS 2013

```
  // GET: api/Questions
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<question> Getquestions()
        {
            return db.questions;
        }
```

I have run out of ideas.

Could someone figure it out?

Thank you.

Comment: STOP IT. Dear god stop returning DB Models directly.

Comment: hi @Phill esay mate, I'm just testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely caused by serialization attempting to lazy load a reference on your question.

If you change your response to have its own response type or dto, it will prevent any lazy loading occuring when serializating.

Something like:

```
// GET: api/Questions
[HttpGet]
public IList<QuestionResponse> Getquestions()
{
    return db.questions.Select(x => new QuestionResponse
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Question = x.Question
    });
}


public class QuestionResponse
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Question {get;set;}
}
```

Also, its bad to return the database model directly, you could potentially expose data to the client that they should not see. By using a response object you control exactly what the client sees irrespective if the db model changes.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I think it's caused by lazy loading too. but I think there will be a way to disable the lazy-loading in some configure file????

Comment: I voted up your answer as you mentioned the lazy-loading part which solves my problem. But here is what I actually did for fixing the bug only(not the best practice):                                                            public My_dbEntities()
            : base("name=My_dbEntities")
        {
            base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

Comment: I'm also interesting why this problem isn't present when testing locally

Comment: @AntonKalcik was this problem solved? Did you know why this problem isn't present when testing locally only when published in Azure? I'm also having this problem, I used this solution but the get doesn't update. Thanks!

Comment: @Katherine See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27007239/53496). The problem was that `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` is mandatory on AzureSQL but not on-premise SQL Server.

Comment: This worked for me! thanks! the problem was I was having a circular dependencies w/ my db design, selecting fields to be called solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Double check if your connection string which you are using to connect to SQL Azure database contains *MultipleActiveResultSets=True* when you are using lazy loading as mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/06/09/remember-to-re-enable-mars-in-your-sql-azure-based-ef-apps.aspx).